# Minimal polynomial coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra

If i have a square matrix over a field and the matrix is invertible how do I show that the coefficient a0 in the minimal polynomial is Not zero?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Let $X^m+a_{m-1}X^{m-1}+a_1X+a_0$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$ and that $a_0=0$. then $(A^{m-1}+a_{m-1}A^{m-2}+\ldots +a_1I)\cdot A=0$, and as $A$ is invertible, $A^{m-1}+a_{m-1}A^{m-2}+\ldots +a_1I=0$, contradicting minimality.

Comment: Thx Hagen von Eitzen, got it know.

Answer (score 0):

The constant coeficient of the minimal polynomial is cero iff cero is root of the minimal polinomial iff cero is root of characteristic polynomial iff the matrix has cero as eigenvalue iff the matrix is singular.

Comment: why is Zero a root if a0 is Zero?

Comment: Ok got it. i can factor out and than one root is Zero.thank you